# Mixed product identity between tensors in Mathematica 9

Tags: matrix, symbolic, tensors

How can we simplify tensor expressions in *Mathematica 9* using the mixed-product identity
$(A\otimes B)(C \otimes D) \equiv AC \otimes BD$ ?

Is it possible to implement this kind of evaluations using the new *Mathematica 9* tensor capabilities?

The following expression is false:

```
TensorProduct[a, b].TensorProduct[c, d] === TensorProduct[ a.c, b.d]
```

I don't really need to prove this identity, but rather to use it for simplifying some expressions. In my case, $a$ and $c$ are some (unknown) symbolic matrices, while $b$ and $d$ are explicit integer $2\times 2$ matrices. I'd like *Mathematica* to evaluate the matrix product between $b$ and $d$ explicitly.

For instance, when

```
b=PauliMatrix[1]; d=PauliMatrix[3];
```

as the product of two Pauli matrices gives another Pauli matrix, I'd like to obtain the simplified result

```
TensorProduct[a.c, -I PauliMatrix[2]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c | d) \[Element] Matrices[{k, k}]

KroneckerProduct[a, b] . KroneckerProduct[c, d] // TensorExpand
```

which returns

```
KroneckerProduct[a.c, b.d]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. The mixed-product identity

   $$ (A\otimes B)(C \otimes D) \equiv AC \otimes BD$$

   is written in terms of the Kronecker product (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations)) not `TensorProduct`. They have different dimensions

   ```
   A = RandomReal[1.0, {10, 10}];
   KroneckerProduct[A, A] // Dimensions
   TensorProduct[A, A] // Dimensions
   ```

   > ```
   > {100, 100}
   > {10, 10, 10, 10}
   > ```
2. `lhs === rhs` gives exact comparison of `lhs` and `rhs`. You need to use `==`.
3. Unfortunately tensors operations with `KroneckerProduct` and `Dot` is not fully implemented in *Mathematica* 9. However, for example, `Dot[a,b]` is equivalent to `TensorContract[a\[TensorProduct]b, {{2, 3}}]`.

Finally, you can rewrite your identity as

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c | d) \[Element] Matrices[{k, k}];

TensorTranspose[
   TensorContract[a\[TensorProduct]b\[TensorProduct]c\[TensorProduct]d, {{2, 5}, {4, 7}}], 
 {1, 3, 2, 4}] == 
 TensorContract[a\[TensorProduct]c, {{2, 3}}]\[TensorProduct]TensorContract[
   b\[TensorProduct]d, {{2, 3}}] // TensorReduce
```

> True

Unfortunately, I can't explain derivation of this formula because I don't understand it completely.

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes me understand a little bit better the new Tensor capabilities of Mathematica 9. However, I'm not able to use your commands for simplifying expression. This was indeed, my main problem. I edited the question to better clarify this point.

Comment: @benkj I think it is much simpler to implement it with pattern replacements or do it manually.