# Simplifying symbolic expressions using TensorExpand

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

Following my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91502/how-to-simplify-symbolic-expressions-with-kroneckerproduct) I have this issue using TensorExpand:

```
KroneckerProduct[x, y].(KroneckerProduct[2 z, w]) // TensorExpand
```

results in:

```
2KroneckerProduct[x.z, y.w]
```

as expected. But why doesn't the following:

```
KroneckerProduct[x, y].(2 KroneckerProduct[z, w]) // TensorExpand
```

produce the same answer, and how should I get it to work?

Again this is a just a small step in my program, so I'm looking for a neat solution (minimum amount of modifying internal functions...)

It works for `x. (2 y) // TensorExpand`

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the fact that Mathematica doesn't reduce `Dot` expressions like `a.2`. I've never been able to resolve an issue of this type without, in this situation, defining an upvalue for `Times` or a downvalue for `KroneckerProduct`.

Comment: I see. Could you please elaborate on this? I'm not familiar with upvalue/downvalue. (I just realized that it works for 

x. (2 y) // TensorExpand )

Comment: Sure. Downvalues are the type of definitions you probably already use pretty regularly, `=` and `:=`. These definitions are associated with the outermost `Head` defined to the left of the operator and are checked when that `Head` is encountered. Upvalues are definitions associated with a `Head` in a subexpression left of it's operators, `^=`, `^:=` and `/:`. For your purposes I'd use define something like `KroneckerProduct/:Dot[KroneckerProduct[x__],Times[a_?NumberQ,b_KroneckerProduct]:=a Dot[KroneckerProduct[x],b]` to always pull out constant coefficients in the `Dot`.

Comment: Thanks. I get error using this (even after fixing the missing bracket.) I'll play with it.

Comment: For whatever reason I am unable to edit my previous comment, but try `KroneckerProduct/:Dot[x_KroneckerProduct, Times[a_?NumberQ, b_KroneckerProduct]] := 
 a Dot[x, b]`. Don't forget to `Unprotect[KroneckerProduct]` first.

Comment: Now I see, thanks. Though I hope I can find a way out of this without modifying Kronecker.

I have several functions defined using Kronecker, and also have expressions like :

`KroneckerProduct[x, y].(2 KroneckerProduct[z, w]).KroneckerProduct[x, 
   y] // TensorExpand` or with more products in my calculation.

Comment: `KroneckerProduct /: 
 Dot[x___KroneckerProduct, Times[a_?NumberQ, b_KroneckerProduct], 
  y___KroneckerProduct] := a Dot[x, b, y]` will work with both your most recent case and the previous one.

Comment: I appreciate it. My worries is that I'm not sure how careful I can use this approach in a large calculation. I have up to 10 Dot, on Kronecker product of 5 symbols. If there is not clean approach maybe I should really go through this approach,
BTW, on you comment it doesn't correctly simplify this one : `(2 KroneckerProduct[x, y]).(2 KroneckerProduct[3 z, 
     w]).KroneckerProduct[z, w] // TensorExpand`

Comment: `Dot[x___, c_?NumberQ*y_, z___] := c Dot[x, y, z]`. This time, `Unprotect[Dot]` since it will be associated with `Dot` now rather than `KroneckerProduct`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) acquired support for this kind of expansion in M11.2 or M11.3:

```
KroneckerProduct[x, y].(2 KroneckerProduct[z, w]) // TensorExpand
```

> 2 KroneckerProduct[x.z, y.w]